# KnpSnappyBundle parameter process_timeout not changable in Symfony 3.3

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony3.x, knp-snappy

In a Symfony 3.3 project I am using KnpSnappyBundle.
In the doc at https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle it says

> You can also configure the timeout used by the generators with process_timeout:

```
# app/config/config.yml
knp_snappy:
    process_timeout: 20 # In seconds
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.
Setting

```
process_timeout: 600 # In seconds
```

has no effect. The timeout remains at 60.
Any ideas on how to change this parameter are very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for php's `max_execution_time`?

Comment: @IwanWijaya good hint. It was max_input_time - but still. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The timeout came from

```
max_input_time
```

in php.ini - not from the process_timeout parameter.
Thanks @iwanwijaya